# Qt Android Application Execution failed

Tags: android, qt

I'm learning developing Android Application by Qt Creator (v4.1.0 Community). When I build my sample app, there's no issue but when I run it with Android x86 Kit (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.7.0), it's failed and I get this message from Compile Output Console (it still runs well when I run with Desktop Qt 5.7.0 MinGW 32 bit):

> 'C++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.
>   'C++\Qt\build-AndroidAppSample-Android_for_x86_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_7_0-Debug\android-build\'
>   is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program
>   or batch file. Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain Building the android package
>   failed!
>   -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
>   21:04:35: The process "C:\Qt\5.7\android_x86\bin\androiddeployqt.exe"
>   exited with code 14. Error while building/deploying project
>   AndroidAppSample (kit: Android for x86 (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.7.0)) When
>   executing step "Build Android APK"

Can anybody explain me what I do wrong or give some ideas to solve it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you install android SDK and NDK tools ?

Comment: Yes, I've already installed Android SDK, Android NDK, Java SDK and Apache Ant. I've also created a compatible AVD emulator

Comment: Looks like you have some spaces in your project path together with some incomplete quotes, and androiddeployqt tries to parse part of the  path "C++" as a command instead of a parameter. For more information, we would probably need to see the line where androiddeployqt is called. Do you have Qt installed in a folder without spaces in the name?

Comment: @FourtyTwo: thank you, I've already solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you see your Android kit get detected automatically ? or was it added by you manually. I would suggest to try the thing I mentioned below and see if that helps.

On Projects, Build Android APK, change the Android build SDK to newer version as shown in the picture below:

[image: build_Android APK version]

Comment: Great. It is advisable to post your solution here so that some one in future may use your solution if they run in to same problem.